# With Xmarks closing down, what is a good alternative?

Tags: firefox, extension, chromium

I'd like to keep my bookmarks synced between different browsers, computers, and operating systems.  What's the best browser plugin or other solution to keep my bookmarks synced between all of these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use delicious http://www.delicious.com/

and whatever browser plug-in I need to access easily.

Comment: The main thing is to figure out a tag and tag bundling strategy that works for you.

Comment: Yeah, tags are way to easy to add... then it gets out of control.

Answer (score 12):

I personally prefer to use [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome?platform=linux), which supports this natively. As a bonus, your bookmarks are also available within a special folder in Google Docs.

Options -> Personal Stuff -> Sync:

[image: screenshot]

This does not synchronize your history or saved passwords.

Comment: I'm looking for something cross browser, but this is a great idea.

Comment: It is cross-browser, so long as the only browser you use is chrome ;)

Comment: And what about passwords? Are they supported?

Comment: I'm not sure if passwords are supported.

Comment: Im pretty sure it doesn't sync passwords.

Comment: @gamerchick02: You can use the LastPass extension for passwords

Answer (score 6):

Since Firefox is still the default browser in Ubuntu, I think it's worth mentioning that Mozilla also developed a syncing add-on called [Sync](http://www.firefox.com/sync). Firefox 4 will have Sync built-in.

Ubuntu One can also sync Firefox bookmarks, but you have to install an add-on called [Bindwood](https://launchpad.net/bindwood) first (there's an "Install" button in the Ubuntu One client for that). Unfortunately, service uptime is [not so good](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Status#Bookmarks) at the moment.

Comment: It's available right now as an extension. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 3):

Xmarks isn't closing down. Check this blog post - http://blog.xmarks.com/?p=1988.
So, do you really need any alternative? =)

Comment: I didn't see this. Thank you for sending it my way. I guess I don't an alternative after all.

Comment: Greetings from the future, where Xmarks is, once again, closing down.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I know this is an old post but I've moved to pinboard.in for bookmarking.  I'm also using pocket for read-it-later services and temporary bookmarking.

If anoyone stumbles upon this little thread, try either of those.